# How to delete a directory using GitHub API?

Tags: javascript, github

I know you can delete a directory using git's `rm -r "folderName"`, and files can be [deleted via the API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#delete-a-file) already, but I cannot see a way this can be achieved.

Currently, I am exploring using the [GitHub Trees](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/#create-a-tree) to do this but have not had any luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since folders are not tracked in a Git repo, you need to delete files only.

That means you need to [recursively get those files](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/#get-a-tree-recursively), before, for each one, [deleting it](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#delete-a-file).

That approach should be scripted and does not scale well though.

Comment: Thanks - it looks like I will have to take this approach

Answer (score 0):

Since a tree contains sub trees and files, I think you could remove a tree from its parent tree to delete this directory (need update all its ancestors as well).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, it's doable by recursive removing of all files inside a folder one by one (separate API call per a file)

Here's how I implemented this (probably, this copypaste will save some time for someone)

```
const ORG_NAME = '{{your_repo_name}}';
const API_URL = 'https://api.github.com';
const MAIN_BRANCH = 'master';

public function __construct()
{   
    //Guzzle used
    $this->client = new Client([
        'auth' => [env('GITHUB_USER'), env('GITHUB_TOKEN')],
        //to b able to work with status codes
        'http_errors' => false,
    ]);

   $this->repoName = {{REPO_NAME}} //I have a setter method but let's don't overcomplicate this here
}

 public function getLatestCommitSHA()
    {
        $res = $this->client->get(self::API_URL."/repos/".self::ORG_NAME."/$this->repoName/git/refs/heads/".self::MAIN_BRANCH);
        if ($res->getStatusCode() !== 200) {
            throw new \Exception("Couldn't get the latest commit from the repo. Status code: ".$res->getStatusCode());
        }
        try {
            return json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents())->object->sha;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new \Exception("Couldn't get the latest commit from the repo.");
        }
    }

    public function getFileSHA(string $location)
    {
        foreach ($this->getRepoContent()->tree as $piece) {
            if ($piece->path == $location) {

                return $piece->sha;
            }
        }

        throw new \Exception("File not found it the repository. Couldn't obtain SHA");
    }

    public function getRepoContent()
    {
        $res = $this->client->get(self::API_URL."/repos/".self::ORG_NAME."/$this->repoName/git/trees/".$this->getLatestCommitSHA(),
            [
                'query' => [
                    'recursive' => true
                ]
            ]
        );

        if ($res->getStatusCode() !== 200 or !$content = json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents())) {
            throw new \Exception("Couldn't get a repository files list");
        }
        //make sure that we received full repo data
        if ($content->truncated) {
            throw new \Exception("The repo content is too large. Contact support, please");
        }

        return $content;
    }

    public function deleteFile(string $location)
    {
        $res = $this->client->delete(self::API_URL."/repos/".self::ORG_NAME."/$this->repoName/contents/$location",
            ['json' =>
                [
                    'message' => "$location file removing (Commit initiated by ".env('APP_NAME')." app).",
                    'sha' => $this->getFileSHA($location)
                ]
            ]);

        return json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents());
    }

    public function deleteFolder(string $folderName)
    {
        try {
            foreach ($this->getRepoContent()->tree as $location) {
                if (str_starts_with($location->path, "public/".$folderName) and $location->type == 'blob') {
                    //TODO make as a job
                    $this->deleteFile($location->path);
                }
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new \Exception($e->getMessage());
        }

        return true;
    }
```

So you need to fill some variables and then call `deleteFolder(string $folderName)`.
In my example I was interested in folders inside a "public" folder but you can just remove or change it if needed. This code still needs tome improvements but I thought that it might be helpful for someone and I can just forget to share when I get it polished some time :)